# Ошибка в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Использую *RecyclerView* с кастомным *ItemDecoration*. Причём разделители между ячейками разные, зависят от типов.

При пролистывании списка всё ок, но проблемы начинаются при использовании *notifyItem****. В таком случае расстояния между ячейками, которые видны на экране и не участвуют в обновлении, меняются. После того, как изменения закончились, при повторном пролистывании опять всё нормально.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
    new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = linearLayoutManager.getPosition(view);
            int type = linearLayoutManager.getItemViewType(view);
            outRect.bottom = getSize(
                type, messageManager.getType(position + 1)
            );
            outRect.left = 0;
            outRect.right = 0;
            outRect.top = getSize(
                messageManager.getType(position - 1), type
            );
        }

        private int getSize(int type1, int type2) {
            if ((type1 & MessageManager.FLAG_MESSAGE) == MessageManager.FLAG_MESSAGE &&
                (type2 & MessageManager.FLAG_MESSAGE) == MessageManager.FLAG_MESSAGE)
                return (type2 & MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST) == MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST &&
                       ((type1 & MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST) == MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST ||
                       (type1 & MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST) != MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST) ?
                       Sizes.DP_8 : Sizes.DP_2;
            return 0;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: подозреваю, что тебе нужно сдвигать все видимые элементы списка...

Comment: Что это значит? Есть пример?

Comment: вот первое что папалось, обрати внимание что бегут по все элементам. https://gist.github.com/alexfu/0f464fc3742f134ccd1e

Comment: Не помогает, так как в методе *onDraw* происходит отрисовка разделителя, а расстояния так же считаются в методе *getItemOffsets*.

Answer (score 2):

Исправил. Оказалось, не тот *position* получал. Ну, и решил вычислять *offset* снизу ячейки, а не сверху и снизу.

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
    new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            outRect.set(
                0, 0, 0, getSize(parent, view)
            );
        }

        private int getSize(int type1, int type2) {
            if ((type1 & MessageManager.FLAG_MESSAGE) == MessageManager.FLAG_MESSAGE &&
                (type2 & MessageManager.FLAG_MESSAGE) == MessageManager.FLAG_MESSAGE)
                return (type2 & MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST) == MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST &&
                       ((type1 & MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST) == MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST ||
                       (type1 & MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST) != MessageManager.FLAG_FIRST) ?
                       Sizes.DP_16 : Sizes.DP_4;
            return 0;
        }

        private int getSize(RecyclerView recyclerView, View view) {
            int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            return getSize(
                messageManager.getType(position),
                messageManager.getType(position + 1)
            );
        }
    }
);
```